# Одномерный массив

Tags: c++, массивы

Описать функцию, которая в новом массиве получит только положительные значения элементов исходного массива. Использовать механизм указателей.

Такой код вызывает кучу ошибок, помогите исправить или найти другой способ.

```
int *Create(int n) 
{
    int *a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    return a;
}


int *Filter(int *a, int &n)
{
    int i, j, c; 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        c += (a[i] < 0);
    }
    int *b = new int[c];
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] < 0) b[j++] = a[i]

        { 
            b[j++] = a[i]
            n = c; 
        }
    }

    return b;
}

//Вывод массива
void Write(int *a, int n) 
{
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << a[i];
        cout << endl;
    } 
}

int n=10;
int *a=Create(n); Write(a,n);
int *b=Filter(a,n); Write(b,n);
```

Comment: Помочь, или написать за Вас?

Comment: Желательно написать

Comment: `if (a[i] < 0)` - только положительные ??

Answer (score -1):

```
int * onlyPositive(int *m, int size)
{
 int a[size], ai=0;
 for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
 {
   if(m[i]>0)
   { 
     a[ai]=m[i]; ai++;
   }
 return a;
}
```

но это не точно)

Comment: чуть плюс не поставил за эту фразу - "но это не точно"

Comment: Даже если закрыть глаза на то, что возвращается из функции, автоматический массив неконстантного размера - это не С++.